# How to Logout using SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am creating a login form using Spring boot. i don't know how to logout.what i tried so far i attached below.

**index.html**

```
 <h1>Welcome to Home Page</h1>
   <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
```

**UserContoller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/logout"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String fetchSignoutSite(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
      

    return "redirect:/login";
   
}
```

**Mehtod not allowed**
**Error**

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Allen D. Ball, modify your `index.html` like below:

```
<h1>Welcome to Home Page</h1>
<a href="/logout" th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
```

Also you have written - `return "redirect:/login";` and, your error indicates -

```
template might not exist or might not be accessible
```

To fix this, make sure you have a `login.html` in your respective (say, `src/main/resources/templates`) location.

Answer (score 0):

You're form is generating a POST but your fetchSignoutSite() method is configured for a GET.  I suggest you use a button or link for logout.